# How does Xor determine which int is different?

Tags: java, logical-operators

here's the problem that's being solved

"You're given three integers, a, b and c. It is guaranteed that two of these integers are equal to each other. What is the value of the third integer? "

here's the code

```
int extraNumber(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a^b^c;
}
```

I understand the caret " ^ " mean XOR, which means "this OR that, but not both" in simple terms but what I fail to understand is how this code determines which int is different from the others, or perhaps I don't understand XOR properly?

Comment: `X ^ X` is `0`. `0 ^ Y` is `Y`. Therefore `X ^ X ^ Y` is always `Y`. The same is true for `X ^  Y ^ X` and `Y ^ X ^ X`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at it at bit-level:

- A value `x` xor-ed with itself will always result in 0 (check: `1^1=0` and `0^0=0`).
- A value `y` xor-ed with 0 will always result in the same value `y` (check: `1^0=1` and `0^0=0`).

Since it holds true for individual bits and `int` are just 32 bits, the same rules hold true for full `int` values.

Therefore the method doesn't need to figure out "which values are different" because a value xor-ed with itself with cancel out to 0 and xor-ing the "remaining" value with 0 will just return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim's answer is correct, and to add bit more details with an example, let's say you pass three arguments (2, 3, 2) to your method, the bit level format usually `...16 8 4 2 1` starts from right side,  as per truth table for XOR,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate

```
private int extraNumber(int a, int b, int c) {
        // 8421  -> this is bit level, 
        // let's compare a^b

        // 0010 = 2 (a value)
        // 0011 = 3 (b value, sum of 2nd + 1st bits)

        // 0001 = 1 (after XOR with a^b)
        // 0010 = 2 (c value)

        // 0011 = 3 (the final output)

        return a^b^c;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check the intermediate results, by breaking up the code a^b^c into two statements.

for example

```
int a = 0b1010_1010;
int b = 0b1010_1010; //same value as b

int c = 0b1111_0000; //the remaining item

//CASE 1 (xor the different values first)
int d = a^c; //  results in 0b0101_1010
int e = d^b; // results in 0b1111_0000 (the answer) 


//CASE 2 (xor the same values first)
int d = a^b; // results in 0b0000_0000
int e = d^c; // results in 0b1111_0000 (the answer)
```